# Java class diagram composition / aggregation for arrays

Tags: java, composition, aggregation, class-diagram

Consider the following:

```
class A {}

class B {
    private A[] a;
}
```

How would I represent the relationship between `A` and `B` on a class diagram? I would use composition / aggregation if `B` only held a single `A` (as opposed to an array), but in this case I'm not sure what should be done. Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I agree with the given answer that if the relationship between B and A is composition (A is part of B) then changing A to an array does not change this.  However your example does not prove to me that you have composition in the first place. Need more context. Class A = Eye Class B = Person - clearly the eyes are part of the person so yes it is composition. Class A = Pet.  A person may have two pets but they are not part of the person.  I'm just pointing out that you may have a more general one-to-many relationship that is not composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing a single reference to an array doesn't change the meaning of composition..

It is still a `composition`..

By `composition` you mean some class A, is composed of a single instance of another class B (One-to-One Mapping), or a list of instances (One-to-Many Mapping)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the convention for labeling the arrow that represents this composition for my example above?

Comment: `B (1)-->(*)A` .. Since it is a One-to-Many mapping, you need to have a 1 on composing class(B) and a * on composed class(A)